# Change size of Panel in Scrollpane

Tags: java, resize, jpanel, scrollpane

So i want to resize a panel thats embedded in a JScrollPane. But it works just one time. Here is my simple code.

```
public void setSizeKarte()
{
    karte1.setSize(karte1.getWidth()+100, karte1.getHeight()+100);
}
```

karte1 <- Panel embedded  in ScrollPane

But I tried things like revalidate. Nothing works. Some hints?

Comment: Your best bet for quick decent help is to create a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one that is very short but that demonstrates your problem for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Java Swing layout managers respect preferredSizes more than sizes. So a quick and easy solution *could* be to call `karte1.setPreferredSize(...)`, but this would risk other problems. Another solution is to override karte1's `getPreferredSize()` method and allow method calls to affect its state and its return.

Note though that for better more thorough help, consider creating a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one that is very short but that demonstrates your problem for us.